# An Ailing Assassin

Tags: visual, rebus, grid-deduction, nonogram

Since moving to the countryside, I've taken up a side job as an assassin. While camping out with a doctor, they told me that I had contracted an illness. However, since I didn't take any money with me, they handed me this puzzle instead:

[image: I'm all charged up for this puzzle to be solved]

They told me, "Solve the nonogram, and you'll know where you're ill!"

> Can you identify where I'm ill?

<sub>*This puzzle can be solved without guessing. Note that cells filled with different colours do not necessarily need to have a gap between them. Clued colors are indicated by the background color of the text.*</sub>

Comment: Also [with hard lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbK4O.png), for solving convenience.

Comment: Nice formatting, by the way ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From Somebody's [completed nonogram grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91935/57742), we can see

> an $ X_2^{-}, $ which could represent an *ion*, underneath what appears to be a *tent*.

Therefore,

> the rebus can be interpreted as "in tent, ion," or **intention**. And this answers the question because an assassin would definitely have *ill intentions*.

Comment: Well done, and nice catch :)

Comment: Nice catch! I saw what you saw but didn't have the rebus solve.

Answer (score 17):

Here is what I have as a completed nonogram. I don't think I've missed anything. I'm not yet sure where to go from here but it's a start!

> [image]

Comment: Congrats on getting the first step! You may want to check the tags of a puzzle to see the components to solving the puzzle. P.S.: Columns 41/42 need a little fixing

Comment: I think I got the solution, hope it's OK that I posted it as a separate answer :)

Comment: @Avi d'oh! should be fixed now!

Comment: @Somebody Looks good now; I hope you enjoyed the puzzle :)